# Not able to debug java code in eclipse in linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, debugging

I am connecting to a linux system through mstsc.

I have an eclipse ide installed there. Strangely the breakpoints are not hitting when i am debugging. Same code is debuggable in local system in Windows.

I did following to check for the issue.

Checked all the steps mentioned here http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug_FAQ#I_can_run_a_program_but_not_debug_it.3F.3F.3F

Checked whether all the debug preferences in the IDE is set properly.

Still could not resolve the issue

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: Do you have the right source linked?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the linux on of my machines and its working fine there.
Seems to be there is some issue if i connect remotely.

My problem is resolved.
But if anyone can add anything to this, it will be great.

cheers,
Saurav